# Revenue Forecast Database Design

Tags: database-design, performance, ms-access

I am currently trying to design an Access database that will house financial data containing forecasting, actuals and prior forecast data.

The current format of the Excel "database" is

```
Customer Name | Contract Number | Region | Product | Fee Type | Commit Type 
| Jan 19 Plan - Dec 2023 Plan | Jan 19 Prior Forecast to Dec 2023 Prior 
Forecast | Jan 19 Forecast - Dec 2023 Forecast
```

Where Jan 19 Plan - Dec 2023 Plan is a set of 59 columns, each month with it's own column, and no column in the entire "database" is unique. And contract numbers will have N/A's or blanks etc. This is my initial design[image]

I'd love any feedback or modifications anyone can provide

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/are-db-modelling-review-questions-on-topic).

Comment: You might also want to look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+iterative) - and check out [database answers](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm) to get you started. This is above all else an iterative process. I would also arise you to use a "real" RDBMS  for your project - I would recommend PostgreSQL!